# Make grep not to change pattern

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I do this:
`file $(ls -td -1 /usr/bin/* | grep zip)`
but the ouput:

```
/usr/bin/preunzip:     cannot open `/usr/bin/preun\033[01;31m\033[Kzip\033[m\033[K' (No such file or directory)
/usr/bin/prezip:       cannot open `/usr/bin/pre\033[01;31m\033[Kzip\033[m\033[K' (No such file or directory)
...
...
```

As could be seen, after piped to grep, the filename change to some trash (`033[01;31...`), and thus the `file` command cannot open this trash. How to make grep (after being piped) to not change the pattern (filenames in my case) to be used for another command?

PS:
without grep, it normally works:
`file $(ls -td -1 /usr/bin/*)`:

```
/usr/bin/js:                                 symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/js
/usr/bin/git:                                ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=f400072e5b2d2e09190d4258071d7502497aa5e3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

So the `grep` causes the problem here

Comment: `ls` is sending color changes.

Comment: You should configure `ls` so it doesn't send color when writing to a pipe.

Comment: You've found just one of the things that can go wrong when parsing `ls`. If I were you, I would not bother debugging what you got because the result would still be a buggy program. See <https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs>.

Comment: Looks more like it's `grep` that's adding the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to run `file` on all files under `/usr/bin` that have `zip` in their names, in order of modification time?

```
file $(find /usr/bin -name "*zip*" -printf "%T@\t%p\n" | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1nr | cut -f2)
```

will do it without most of [the perils associated with using `ls` output in a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

If for some reason you have a file with whitespace character(s) in the name in that directory tree:

```
find /usr/bin -name "*zip*" -printf "%T@\t%p\0" | sort -zt$'\t' -k1,1nr | cut -zf2- | xargs -0 file
```

(All this assumes GNU versions of the utilities)

If you don't care about the order:

```
find /usr/bin -name "*zip*" -exec file '{}' +
```

Comment: Yeah, but i am deliberately used `grep` to find out, why it does not work in pipe, so your solution does solve the problem but with other commands. I want to know how to do it with grep being piped, so use grep for my purpose (I know there are more way to do it, but the question is about the grep)

Comment: grep is aliased to `grep --color=always'

Comment: @Herdsman Well, that's why it's printing out the color escape sequences even when output's not to a terminal. Change where ever that alias is defined (`~/.profile`? `~/.bashrc`?) to use `--color=auto` instead.